# can not be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I have this code. I am getting error "can not be resolved to a variable" on line

```
if (zip2Value != "NA") {
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
if (zip2Col == null) {
    String zip2Value = "NA";
}
else
{
     String zip2Value = NumberToTextConverter.toText(zip2Col.getNumericCellValue());
        System.out.println("zip2Value " + zip2Value);
}

if (zip2Value != "NA") {

    citiesweservePage.enterZip2(zip2Value);
    citiesweservePage.enterZip3(zip3Value);
}
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but that's not how you compare string values (almost always) in Java, so it won't work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It's due to scope. The variable is declared and set in the if and else. Declare the variable before the first if for it to survive longer.

You should also use .equals for String comparison.